# Classification or regression for prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, classification

I want to train a Neural Network to predict classes/ numbers out of an input which is also a number; so the mapping is number->number (input->output).

But when considering the datatype and the values I am not sure whether to treat the problem as a classification or regression problem.

As an example the first rows of the data look like this:

Since my target ranges from 0-14 my first approach was to treat this problem as a classification problem where i choose the size of the output layer to be size = 15.

Here is my NN model:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Activation, Dropout, LSTM, Conv1D



model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(15, activation='softmax'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))



model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=128)
```

which predicts always the same classification values:

The accuracy converges after a few epochs and does not change any more at about 20%.

Why is the model always predicting the same class? what am I missing here? Should I treat this problem as a regression task?

Comment: classification makes sense (if you can plot you dataset, or at least some part of it, we could say more), it seems you have a bug somewhere.  I would start by checking X_train, y_train to see that the data you feed into the model is correct

Comment: From just looking at the example data, it does look really messy and troublesome for classification. The overall code is not wrong, you can get better results if you start to overfit your network as in increase the layers/architecture. You can also try doing some batch_normalization.

Comment: @CeliusStingher instead of increasing the architecture do you think treating the problem as regression would work better? unfortunatelly the overall data looks like this and is very messy/chaotic

Comment: I'm not sure there is need for a densenet, I would give `np.polyfit` a try.

Comment: I highly doubt it will work better as you will run into many issues, mostly regarding violation of gauss-markov theorem. You can try as it won't hurt at all. Go for a regression approach and then you can try to find a function (with NN too) that approximates this regression output to a value between 0-14 so as to match the target. Would you mind sharing us a scatter plot regarding distribution of the data? To do some basic VEDA

Comment: @CeliusStingher I added the scatter plot to my question. what do you mean by VEDA ? and which function maps the output value between 0-14?

Comment: Thanks. VEDA stands for visual exploratory data analysis. There is no one function, that is for the network/algorithm to build. We create a network that takes as input the output from the regression an algorithm and use the target as y value.

Comment: If your target values are orderable in the sense that 14 > 13 and so on you could use ordinal regression https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression. This way you can use the intermediate decimal values as a sort of probability in between classes.

Comment: @CeliusStingher I tried out a regressional NN which predicts as bad as the previous model.. what do you think could I do next to improve the prediction power?

Comment: Do you think you could send me the details of the data and I can try a few approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already applied 'softmax' in `model.add(Dense(15, activation='softmax'))` 
so there is no need to apply it again by `model.add(Activation('softmax'))`.

Remove it and try.

Comment: I have tried this now, but the problem is still existing and nothing has changed..

Answer (score 1):

Typically, numbers (or any numerics) are used for regression and labels (any non-numerics) are used for classification.

https://medium.com/quick-code/regression-versus-classification-machine-learning-whats-the-difference-345c56dd15f7

Regression Data:

[image]

Classification Data:

[image]

Look at the data types in both the regression example and the classification example.